# Django URLs for SEO - Multiple Patterns Pointing to Domain

Tags: python, django, url, seo

Currently I have URL Pattern with business name pointing to the: domain.com/business-name/

```
url(r'^(?P<business>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.business'),
```

My goal is to add another URL pattern for location search to also point to the domain as domain.com/location-name/

```
url(r'^(?P<location>[-\w]+)/$', 'views.location'),
```

Currently only the URL pattern listed first would work.

Is there a way to have something like this?:

```
TRY THIS URL FIRST 
  url(r'^(?P<business>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.business'), 
IF NOTHING TRY 
  url(r'^(?P<location>[-\w]+)/$', 'views.location'),
```

Comment: URL patterns are simply tried in the order they are specified. Sounds like you're really needing to check for the existence of an object and redirect if not found. Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Not trying to redirect, just to have all urls short without additional "/path/" values. Pretty much would prefer to have all urls pointing to domain.com/some-value/ instead of domain.com/location/some-value/

Comment: In that case, your current URL scheme should work. If the first pattern can't be matched, Django will just move on to the next.

Comment: Thats what I thought too but for some reason it will only process the one listed above the other. If I swap them, the result is reversed too. My work around for now is to add additional value (banks) inside the url: url(r'^(?P<location>[-\w]+)-banks/$', 'views.location'), so the url will look like domain.com/new-york-banks/

Comment: Sounds like a good time to write a functional test to figure out why :)